# How to calculate route from source to destination using skobbler in ios?

Tags: ios

`SKRouteSettings` is used to set the route conditions including start coordinate, endCoordinates, etc.

After that, `SKRoutingService` calls a delegate method `calculateRoute` by passing the route from above `SKRouteSettings`. This method is supposed to call either `didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo` or `routingServiceDidFailRouteCalculation` methods of `SKRoutingService` but none is called.

Can anyone please help me determine where I am going wrong?

Comment: add relevant codes to this question !

Comment: add some snippet to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
#import <SKMaps/SKMaps.h>
 @implementation RoutingViewController<SKRoutingDelegate>
     - (void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     SKMapView *mapView =[[SKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f,  CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) )];
     [SKRoutingService sharedInstance].routingDelegate = self; // set for receiving routing callbacks
     [SKRoutingService sharedInstance].mapView = mapView; // use the map view instance for route rendering
     SKRouteSettings* route = [[SKRouteSettings alloc]init];
     route.startCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.447692, -122.166016);
     route.destinationCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.437964, -122.141147);
     route.shouldBeRendered = YES; // If NO, the route will not be rendered.
     route.routeMode = SKRouteCarFastest;
     route.maximumReturnedRoutes = 1;
     SKRouteRestrictions routeRestrictions = route.routeRestrictions;
     routeRestrictions.avoidHighways = YES;
     route.routeRestrictions = routeRestrictions;
     [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] calculateRoute:route];
     }
     - (void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo:(SKRouteInformation*)routeInformation{
     NSLog(@"Route is calculated.");
     [routingService zoomToRouteWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero duration:1]; // zoom to current route
     }
     - (void)routingServiceDidFailRouteCalculation:(SKRoutingService *)routingService{
     NSLog(@"Route calculation failed.");
     }
     @end
```

Comment: I did the same but after calculateRoute method neither of the two methods are being called.